# Android Studio Got stuck on loading Screen on macbook

Tags: macos, android-studio

**
I am trying to launch Android Studio. It is Stuck On this page.

I am using macOS Ventura 13.4.1. 16 Gb ram. I have Given 4 gb for android studio.
cleaned all kinds of android studio-related paths and reinstalled again. after all this this problem is still not solved.
can anyone suggest to me what can i do?

**
[image: image can be found here]

Comment: Could [this](https://www.ithinkdiff.com/open-apps-using-rosetta-mac-m1/) help?